# Different result with Mathematica for $\int \frac{x}{x^2 + \frac{1}{4}}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, mathematica

I am confused why Mathematica gives a different answer with this simple integral:

$$
\int \frac{x}{x^2 + \frac{1}{4}}\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\log(x^2 +\frac{1}{4}) + C.
$$

Mathematica produces 
$$
 \frac{1}{2}\log(4x^2 + 1).
$$

Comment: Bot are same upto a constant. Please note that an arbitrary constant of integration is allowable and in this case this $C$ is nothing but $ \log 2.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same set of solutions, note that $$\log(4x^2+1)=\log(4(x^2+1/4))=\log4+\log(x^2+1/4)$$ So $\frac12\log4$ can be added to the constant of integration.

Answer (score 4):

The two solutions are the same after working with logarithms and throwing the constants in $C$

Note that $\log (4x)=\log4+\log x$